# ¿Como insertar la imagen seleccionada con tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

estoy intentando hacer que el programa se pueda insertar la imagen que se selecciona, la imagen se guarda en una carpeta "Imagenes" que esta dentro de la carpeta principal del codigo. La idea es que la imagen al abrirla se vea en el label, pero he intentado y no se como poder seleccionarla.
Este es el codigo que tengo actualmente:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import os
#Ventana
ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("500x500")
#Variables
archivo_abierto = None
imagen = PhotoImage(archivo_abierto)

def abrir_archivo():
    global archivo_abierto
    archivo_abierto = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",
                                                 title="Seleccione archivo", filetypes=(("png files", "*.png"),
                                                                                        ("all files", "*.*")))
    print(archivo_abierto)
    imagen=PhotoImage(archivo_abierto)
    lbImagen=Label(ventana, image=imagen).place(relx=.5, rely=.1,relwidth=.4,relheight=.5)
def guardar_archivo():

    if archivo_abierto:
            os.getcwd()
            os.chdir('Imagenes')
            archivo_guardado = os.path.join((os.getcwd()), os.path.split(archivo_abierto)[1])

            with open(archivo_abierto, 'rb') as abierto:
                with open(archivo_guardado, 'wb') as guardado:
                 guardado.write(abierto.read())

    print(archivo_guardado)



def carpeta():
    directorio = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if directorio != "":
        os.chdir(directorio)
    print(os.getcwd())


lbImagen=Label(ventana, image=imagen).place(relx=.5, rely=.1,relwidth=.4,relheight=.5)
Button(text="Abrir archivo", bg="pale green", command=abrir_archivo).place(relx=.10, rely=.10, relheight=.1, relwidth=.3)
Button(text="Guardar archivo", bg="light blue", command=guardar_archivo).place(relx=.10, rely=.40, relheight=.1, relwidth=.3)
Button(text="Directorio", bg="salmon", command=carpeta).place(relx=.10, rely=.70, relheight=.1, relwidth=.3)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Seria de gran ayuda poder entender como insertar la imagen seleccionada con "abrir_archivo".
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He tomado tu código, quité todo el código innecesario para este ejemplo y preparé el que encontrarás a continuación, donde el usuario puede seleccionar una imagen con el diálogo y esta imagen se muestra en la ventana.

Un punto importante es que, para que la imagen se muestre correctamente, debes mantener una referencia al `PhotoImage` creado; si esta referencia no se mantiene, la imagen podría no mostrarse. De allí que se declare la variable `imagen` al inicio del script y se referencie a esta variable global dentro de la función `abrirArchivo()`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog

ventana = tk.Tk()
imagen = None

def abrirArchivo():
    global imagen
    archivo_abierto = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", 
                      title="Seleccione archivo", filetypes=(("png files", "*.png"),("all files", "*.*")))
    print(archivo_abierto)
    if (archivo_abierto):
        imagen = tk.PhotoImage(file=archivo_abierto)
        lbImagen = tk.Label(ventana, image=imagen).place(relx=.5, rely=.1,relwidth=.4,relheight=.5)

ventana.geometry("500x500")
tk.Button(text="Abrir archivo", bg="pale green", command=abrirArchivo).place(relx=.10, rely=.10, relheight=.1, relwidth=.3)
ventana.mainloop()
```